# How to deploy asp.net core webapps to a Linux server?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, web-deployment

How to deploy an **asp.net core** webapp to a Linux server (preferably Fedora)? I did not find any clear guideline on the website. Is it possible to xcopy deploy, without using mono?

Comment: Good question. I'm trying to write a bash script which builds (this is currently not possible on Ubuntu bash on Windows 10 due to a [bug in the latest CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4045)) and publishes the project. Then `rsync` the publish folder to my remote server using `expect` and finally try to run it. But I'm currently stuck at the last step and find absolutely no resources about that on internet.